# Is having two verbs in a sentence acceptable?

Tags: grammaticality

> Kremlin spokesman Dmitry Peskov warned the ongoing debate over sending German-made Leopard 2 tanks to Ukraine suggests that the “nervousness among the members of the alliance is constantly growing.”

The phrase above is from a CNN article. I'd like to know if having two verbs,'warned' and 'suggests' in the sentence is right?

Comment: We're always saying that "relativizer" ***that*** is *optional*, but I think it was a really poor stylistic choice *not* to include it after ***warned*** in the cited text. The lack of that "courtesy to the reader" made even me stumble to parse the text, so I'm sure it would have thrown many others off as well. But there's nothing remotely unusual about ***warning** that X **suggests** Y*.

Comment: "That" is not introducing a relative clause, so it's not a 'relativiser' but a simple subordinator (subordinating conjunction in trad grammar).

Comment: Yes, no problem. Many verbs take finite content clauses as complements. These clauses may also use a verb that takes a clause as complement, and that clause, in turn, may use a verb that takes a clause as a complement too. So the following sentence is perfectly fine: "Araucaria knows that Bill suspects that Fumblefungers believes that Father Christmas exists" <--- and all of the *that*s there are optional. (Would have answered but the question was closed ...)

Comment: (Btw, a pedant might want to add that the title of the question has two verbs in it already!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is acceptable English. It means the same as "...warned that...", so we have two levels of noun clause (or [declarative content clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause), to be more precise -- thanks to BillJ in the comments). Here "that" is optional, but the sentence would perhaps have been clearer to non-native speakers if it had been left in.

Other examples where "that" is optional:

- He said (that) he was ill.
- I know (that) you like peaches.

This usually happens after common verbs like "say", "know", "see", and I would say it is unusual to drop "that" after "warned". But this is a matter of style.

Comment: I don't think you mean relative clause.

Comment: @BillJ: Yes, I was careless. But after scouting around on the various grammar sites, I am at a loss as to what to call such a construct! Is it a noun clause? Is it just a "that-clause" (a catch-all term that is new to me)?

Comment: Tony: it's sometimes called a _that_ clause, but its proper name is 'declarative content clause'.

Comment: Thanks @BiilJ, I've edited my post.